# Codable Data Model - self used before all stored properties are initialized

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm trying to create a data model for Codable JSON data that's being fetched (and sent) to a server. The two questions I have are

1. How do I design the model so I can create a new model object, set properties and send it to the server?
2. How do I design the model with an encoder init that won't complain with above error?

Here's an example of how one of my models look:

```
struct TestRailSection : Codable
{
    let id:Int
    let suiteID:Int
    let parentID:Int
    let depth:Int
    let displayOrder:Int
    let name:String
    let description:String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey
    {
        case id           = "id"
        case suiteID      = "suite_id"
        case parentID     = "parent_id"
        case displayOrder = "display_order"
        case depth        = "depth"
        case name         = "name"
        case description  = "description"
    }

    init(name:String, description:String)
    {
        id = 0
        suiteID = 0
        parentID = 0
        depth = 0
        displayOrder = 0
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
    }

    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws
    {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do { id           = try values.decode(Int.self,    forKey: .id) }           catch { id = 0 }
        do { suiteID      = try values.decode(Int.self,    forKey: .suiteID) }      catch { suiteID = 0 }
        do { parentID     = try values.decode(Int.self,    forKey: .parentID) }     catch { parentID = 0 }
        do { depth        = try values.decode(Int.self,    forKey: .depth) }        catch { depth = 0}
        do { displayOrder = try values.decode(Int.self,    forKey: .displayOrder) } catch { displayOrder = 0 }
        do { name         = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name) }         catch { name = ""}
        do { description  = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .description) }  catch { description = "" }
    }

    init(to encoder:Encoder) throws
    {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(suiteID, forKey: .suiteID)
        try container.encode(parentID, forKey: .parentID)
        try container.encode(depth, forKey: .depth)
        try container.encode(displayOrder, forKey: .displayOrder)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(description, forKey: .description)
    }
}
```

I can fetch data from server successfully with this but how do I create a model for encoding? Is the extra init (the one without en/decoder) necessary? Can it be done in a better way? Above error complains that properties aren't initialized in the encoder init.

Comment: You are getting this error because you are implementing the wrong initializer `init(to encoder:Encoder)`. There is nothing like this. To be able to conform to `Encodable` protocol, you need to implement `func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws { ... }`. I recommend you read [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it. if you create a proper answer I will accept it.

Comment: Well, I've just made my comment into answer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) is composed of [`Encodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable) & [`Decodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) protocols. To conform to `Codable` protocol you need to implement the required method(s) and initializer(s). To satisfy the `Codable` requirements you need to implement:

- [`encode(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable/2893603-encode)
- [`init(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable/2894081-init)

---

In your case you are implementing the **wrong** requirement to satisfy the `Codable`. Nothing like **`init(to encoder:Encoder)`** exists in the `Codable` requirements. Instead you will likely implement the `encode(to:)`-

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(suiteID, forKey: .suiteID)
    try container.encode(parentID, forKey: .parentID)
    try container.encode(depth, forKey: .depth)
    try container.encode(displayOrder, forKey: .displayOrder)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    try container.encode(description, forKey: .description)
}
```

To know a little bit more, you should take a look at [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).